# Will wxxWidget's input system work as an OpenGL input handler?

Tags: opengl, sdl, wxwidgets

I know it detects mouse and keyboard events for itself, but will it detect events on the OpenGL canvas? Do I have to use SDL for input handling on the canvas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will and no you don't need SDL. I write OpenGL programs using wxWidgets (and wxPython) and the keyboard/mouse handling on wxGLCanvas and subclasses is identical to any other view.

All windowing systems (well, all the ones I've worked with) separate rendering from input handling. The mouse/keyboard event code just cares about the window size on the screen and where it is in the stacking order, not how you draw the contents.

You may need to adjust event mouse coords from origin at top left to OpenGL origin at bottom left.